# bitwise expression as a for loop condition

Tags: c, for-loop, expression

The goal of my code is to print all the even numbers from 0 to 20. Instead of using the modulus operation, I tried to use the bitwise operator, `&`, to find the even numbers. My problem with the code is that I get this message, "pause: command not found".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int j;
  for (j = 0; j <= 20 && (j & 1); ++j)
  {
    printf("%3d\n", j);
  }

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `j & 1` is fine, it is `true` for odd numbers and `false` for even numbers. The problem is where you use it. As it is now, the `for` loop ends when it reaches the first even number. Put the test inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Don't you think that the message " pause: command not found" has nothing to do with bitwise operators?

Comment: > "This is pretty easy but I wanted to challenge myself and write a hackier, clever code" please don't. there are plenty more useful ways to challenge yourself.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier I was trying to break my code so I could see what works and what doesn't work. In this case, I was missing a very simple concept.

Answer (score 3):

Why not keep it simple and increment by 2 and use getchar instead of pause

```
for (j = 0; j <= 20; j += 2)
{
    printf("%3d\n", j);
}

char ch = getchar();
```

Comment: Nice! I can't think any better way.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int j;
  for (j = 0; j <= 20; ++j)
  {
    if (!(j & 1)) printf("%3d\n", j);
  }

  printf("Enter a number to continue");
  scanf("%d",&j);
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is you put your `&` expression as part of the loop condition, which terminated the loop early.

Then the computer complains about the system pause thing, so I changed that to request keyboard input ........ this will give you the desired pause... but read on because there is a refinement you should see...

or perhaps better after suggestion by @usr2564301

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char ch;
  int j;
  for (j = 0; j <= 20; ++j)
  {
    if (!(j & 1)) printf("%3d\n", j);
  }

  printf("Hit <enter> to continue");
  ch=getc(stdin);
  return 0;
}
```

This is better practice as `scanf` can be a bit fragile.

Comment: @usr2564301 - yes, you are correct -- that is better - edited code with that added as another example.

Comment: Thanks. I don't how to explain, but I had a wrong intuitive understanding of how for loops work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with your loop, it's the `system("pause")`. That is trying to execute the pause command, which doesn't exist on your computer (or, at least, it's not in your $PATH).

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that line, but if you remove it your code should work.

Comment: It's a common Windows thing to prevent "my answer appears but the window disappears immediately!!!". There are tons of proper C methods that could be used here, rather than delegating it to the OS.

Comment: what I meant is, why is the loop not printing the even numbers. I got the answers now.

Answer (score 0):

`system("pause");` only works on Windows. It isn't necessarily available on other OSes.

Comment: my operating system is macOS

Comment: That is why pause isn't recognized by the shell. I had the same problem when switching from windows to linux. You should use getchar instead